# Invoke ViewComponent where derived type and parameters are unknown at compile time (in View)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a project where I want most of the UI rendered via ViewComponents and partial classes. I would like the Views that invoke these ViewComponents to be unaware of the type of ViewComponent that they are invoking along with the data that the ViewComponent needs. Those specifics are determined up-the-chain.

I can keep the Views unaware of the ViewComponent types by passing in the component's name with a ViewModel, like so:

```
@model ShopList.ViewModels.IndexViewModel<Item>

@foreach (var i in Model.Elements)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Component.Invoke(Model.ViewComponentName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Here things work as intended and I'm smiling. The trouble arises when a ViewComponent requires arbitrary data for its `Invoke()`.

If I pass the data with the ViewModel and use it in `Invoke()`, then all ViewComponents are forced to acknowledge it even if they don't require it. Also, I could just make the ViewComponents gather their own data instead of accepting some from the invoking view, but that's wasteful and they'd be less reusable.

Is there a way I can pass data to a ViewComponent without it being hard-coded in the View? Or, maybe I'm on the wrong path; is there a better approach?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your issue? I'm thinking of doing the same kind of thing in my application and came to the same questionning as you.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I have plans on looking back over that approach at some point, but as it stands it remains unresolved.